# libx265 -crf transparency

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency, lossless

I would like to know (even if it is subjective opinion) what is considered "transparency" when encoding with libx265. In other words, what value do I need to put after "-crf" to get a video that has indistinguishable quality compared to the original? I understand that -crf 23 is default for h264 whereas -crf 28 is default for h265 and that the two are roughly the same in quality but h265 would be half the file size. I've also read that crf 17 or 18 using h264 would appear "lossless". This leads me to think that crf 22 or 23 would be what I want for h265. Would this be correct or am I way off?

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17637